# Response body not parsed when API returns http 400

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-webapi, powerapps-modeldriven

When making requests to the [Powerapps Model Driven / Dynamics Client API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/retrievemultiplerecords), if you make a mistake in any of your query strings, you get a blank error object returned. Even though the response body contains an error object, it doesn't get parsed.

Following the example from the documentation linked above for `retrieveMultipleRecords`, I have an entity with a lookup field to a user called `new_OfferedBy`. In order to filter that to a particular user, you need to filter on `/systemuserid`. If you get the name of any property wrong (case sensitive), you get a 400 response. The example below will return a 400 response.

```
// this query looks for the systemuser property when it should look for systemuserid
// this.currentUser returns the guid of the current user

var query = "?$filter=new_OfferedBy/systemuser eq (" + this.currentUser() +")";

Xrm.WebApi
    .retrieveMultipleRecords("new_lastaskswap", query)
    .then(
        function success(result) {
            console.log("Result Success:");
            console.log(result);
            // perform additional operations on retrieved records
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("Error from .then():");
            console.log(error);
            // handle error conditions
        }
    )
```

It outputs the following information into the console, which is not at all useful.

`{errorCode: 2147951872, message: "", code: 2147951872, innerror: undefined}`

However, if you look at the actual response from the request in Chrome devtools, you can see that the response body is populated with JSON describing the error in a useful manner:

[image]

Why is the response body not being parsed by the API when it returns a 400, Is that not the expected behaviour?

Comment: I can't specifically speak for the Dynamics API, but when creating a Custom Connector in PowerApps (to be used with Canvas apps), you have to define the possible responses. Is there an option for you to define a 400 response as part of your connection in Dynamics?

Comment: Well you would think that's what the error function is for, but it doesn't parse the response

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors in your code I believe,

1. your query is probably wrong, field `new_OfferedBy` is lookup
   for Systemuser but you do not need /systemuser you can directly give
   Guid of a user.
2. `Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveMultipleRecords` and not `Xrm.WebApi .retrieveMultipleRecords`

   var query = "?$filter=new_OfferedBy eq (" + this.currentUser().replace(/[{}]/g, "") +")";

   ```
       Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveMultipleRecords("new_lastaskswap", query)
           .then(
               function success(result) {
                   console.log("Result Success:");
                   console.log(result);
                   // perform additional operations on retrieved records
               },
               function (error) {
                   console.log("Error from .then():");
                   console.log(error);
                   // handle error conditions
               }
           )
   ```

Here is one of my code for account entity

```
Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveMultipleRecords("account", "?$select=accountid,accountnumber&$filter=_createdby_value eq 1234567897").then(
    function success(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.entities.length; i++) {
            var accountid = results.entities[i]["accountid"];
            var accountnumber = results.entities[i]["accountnumber"];
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    }
);
```

Comment: Plus, you are actually wrong about 1. it should be `new_OfferedBy/systemuserid` with the id on the end, if you do it without, the response body contains an error saying `"A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemuser' and 'Edm.Guid'` but it doesn't get returned to the error function

Comment: I did not saw on question anywhere intentional you were throwing error 400.
W.r.t  new_OfferedBy/systemuserid I just fired a query on Dynamics crm without systemuserid  and did it returned me correct value  _createdby_value eq 940A9E4A-623A-E911-A831-000D3A385E93". Hence no need for systemuserid.

Anyways when I basically fire webapi call and there are typo or any other error it does give Error details and I see even you get Response as  Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);

Comment: you are using `_createdby_value `, that's not the same as the field name. My problem is that I get the error in the body of the request response but it's not getting parsed by the api into the error function, that is literally the title of the question..